# A problem with graphic function of 13.10 unity desktop

Tags: unity, 13.10

It's a little bit hard for me to describe my problem with words, look at the screenshot
[image: screenshot]
The images just cannot fade away when they are supposed to so that they just mess up together.

Comment: That picture is not in this link !!.

Comment: sorry, since my account doesn't have enough reputations, I was not able to add a pic link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the exact same problem. Does everything else work ok though? What I tried and found very funny that it worked, is create a new userID and then log out of your normal ID and into this new userID. Does the problem go away? For me, it does.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/376026/ubuntu-13-13-ubuntu-desktop-and-only-desktop-freezes-apps-work-mouse-works

Desktop - no worky: http://www.udonet.com/laura/files/trying-to-get-to-desktop-no-worky.png

Also try in your normal userID to add a Wallpaper to your desktop. Or do you just get a black screen? Can you add a Wallpaper to your desktop in the new test userID?

Comment: yeah,I just get a black screen,and desktop freezes, everything else works OK. I think we are having the same problem. thanks:)